# I am trying to achieve a Disaster recovery for Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, high-availability, disaster-recovery, mongodb-3.2, mongodb-3.6

Right now i have a MongoDb HA in site one and i need another site with asynchronous replication enables in another location.This is a base plan of mine to achieve a disaster recovery .
I dont have that much idea on how to establish async replication of mongo .
Also i need this to be done in windows system .

Comment: Please refer https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/#asynchronous-replication

Comment: Also, please explain little more about your current HA deployment architecture like how many nodes in your replica set, how many are data bearing nodes and how many are not? What is your current problem with the deployment and what you are trying to achieve in little more details

Answer (score 3):

I've discovered MongoShake (https://github.com/alibaba/MongoShake) which is an open source Golang application which does cluster to cluster replication and has been made by Alibaba.

The documentation is focused on its internal work/behaviour, and can be discouraging but you have to look at the example configuration file instead which describe each configuration options (https://github.com/alibaba/MongoShake/blob/develop/conf/collector.conf).
In the majority of the cases, as far as I understood it (not tried it yet), you have 2 options to configure:

- [`mongo_urls`](https://github.com/alibaba/MongoShake/blob/develop/conf/collector.conf#L66) which tells where is/are the MongoDB source(s)
- [`tunnel.address`](https://github.com/alibaba/MongoShake/blob/develop/conf/collector.conf#L88) which tells to where the data should be synced

This allows you to replicate, asynchronously, a MongoDB cluster from one datacenter to another one.

There is also [a 48 minutes tutorial video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fAWwH6mxSWA) which explains all the replication you can achieve with MongoShake, and also shows a demo of a MongoDB cluster in Singapour replicating to Jakarta, Indonesia.

This solution is quite young, and there is no English blog article showing it, nor official Docker image on Docker Hub (only 3 images without any documentation ).

To me it look promising and needs more write/test/love to rise.

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement it seems like that only you want two Data Center (i.e HA(primary or Data Center 1) & DR (Secondary or Data Center 2)).

As per MongoDB documentation [Priority 0 Replica Set Members](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-priority-0-member/#replica-set-secondary-only-members)

One data center hosts the primary and a secondary. A second data center hosts a secondary with priority 0. Only the members in data center 1 can become primary.

A [priority 0](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#rsconf.members[n].priority) member is a member that cannot become [primary](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-primary) and cannot trigger [elections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-election). Priority 0 members can acknowledge write operations issued with  [write concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/#write-concern) of w : . For "majority" write concern, the priority 0 member must also be a voting member (i.e. [members[n].votes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#rsconf.members[n].votes) is greater than 0) to acknowledge the write. Non-voting replica set members (i.e. [members[n].votes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#rsconf.members[n].votes) is 0) cannot contribute to acknowledging write operations with "majority" write concern.

Other than the aforementioned restrictions, secondaries that have [priority 0](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#rsconf.members[n].priority) function as normal secondaries: they maintains a copy of the data set, accept read operations, and vote in elections.

Configure a secondary to have priority 0 to prevent it from becoming primary, which is particularly useful in multi-data center deployments.

for further your ref [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/) and [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-architecture-geographically-distributed/)